# Calculate Monthly Leave Balance

Tags: sql-server

I have table structure that is getting the leave details about the employee. I want to calculate how many leaves an employee have earned for each month along with leave type.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmpID Int Primary Key,
Name Varchar(25)
);

CREATE TABLE LeaveBalance
(
BalanceID Int Primary Key,
Balance Int,
EmpID Int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmpID)
);

CREATE TABLE Leave
(
ID Int,
LeaveType Varchar(25),
AppliedOn Date,
ApprovedOn Date,
EmpID Int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmpID),
BalanceID Int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LeaveBalance(BalanceID)

);



INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, 'Erick')
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (2, 'John')


INSERT INTO LeaveBalance VALUES (1, 25, 1)
INSERT INTO LeaveBalance VALUES (2, 15, 2)

INSERT INTO Leave VALUES (1, 'Sick Leave', '2017-12-21', '2017-12-22', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO Leave VALUES (2, 'Casual Leave', '2017-12-26', '2017-12-26', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO Leave VALUES (3, 'Sick Leave', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-11', 1, 1)
INSERT INTO Leave VALUES (4, 'Casual Leave', '2017-12-26', '2017-12-26', 2, 2)
INSERT INTO Leave VALUES (5, 'Earned Leave', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-11', 2, 2)
```

Comment: When you say leave earned, do you mean, "leave taken"?

Comment: @M.Ali Yes exactly

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far? Also, what is your expected output here? You have different examples of leave "sick" and "casual", are these the same for the purposes of your goal??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as (assuming you go by the date AppliedOn and not the Date ApprovedOn):

```
SELECT 
      EmpID
    , LeaveType 
    , YEAR(AppliedOn)   AS [Year]
    , MONTH(AppliedOn)  AS [Month]
    , Count(*)          AS [LeaveTaken]
FROM #Leave
GROUP BY EmpID
    , LeaveType 
    , YEAR(AppliedOn)   
    , MONTH(AppliedOn)
```